# When I try to initialize my List in the initState it gives an error that says that it can't use themes because the theme could change

Tags: flutter

I have a Widget for a settings page and that widget has a List with the settings. But because a ListView has a ItemBuild that loops trough an array I try to initialize that array in the initState. But when I try to do that I get the following error

[image]

I cannot use theme data in my initState because the theme could change. The items in the list are static and won't be dynamically created. Isn't is possible to skip using the item build and just render the items as children? I don't want to use a column because I like the style of the list with the seperators.

```
class _TheSettingsPageState extends State<TheSettingsPage> {

  List<Widget> settings;
  bool _isMilesPerHour = globals.preferences.speedNotation.isMilesPerHour;
  bool _isKilometersPerHour = globals.preferences.speedNotation.isKilometersPerHour;
  File _pickedImage;

  @override
  @mustCallSuper
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      settings =     
      [
        Text(
          'Account',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
        ),
        ListTile
        (
          title: Text('Profile'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.edit),
        ),
        Text('Style'),
        ListTile
        (
          title: Text('Background Image'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.edit),
        ),
        ListTile
        (
          title: Text('Dark Mode'),
          trailing: Switch(
            value: true, 
            onChanged: (isDarkmode) => print(isDarkmode),
          ),
        ),
        Text('Units'),
        ListTile
        (
          title: Text(SpeedNotation.milesPerHour.shortNotation),
          trailing: Switch(
            value: _isMilesPerHour, 
            onChanged: _onMilesPerHourToggled
          ),
        ),
        ListTile
        (
          title: Text(SpeedNotation.kilometersPerHour.shortNotation),
          trailing: Switch(
            value: _isKilometersPerHour, 
            onChanged: _onKilometersPerHourToggled
          ),
        ),
      ];
    });
  }

  _onMilesPerHourToggled(bool isMilesPerHour){
    setState(() {
      _isMilesPerHour = isMilesPerHour;
      _isKilometersPerHour = !isMilesPerHour;
    });
    globals.preferences.writeSettings();
  }

  _onKilometersPerHourToggled(bool isKilometersPerHour){
    setState(() {
      _isKilometersPerHour = isKilometersPerHour;
      _isMilesPerHour = !isKilometersPerHour;
    });
    globals.preferences.writeSettings();
  }

  Future getImageAsync() async{
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _pickedImage = image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column
        (
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: 
          [ 
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Stack
              (
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: NavigatePopButton(),
                  ),
                  Align
                  (
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Text
                    (
                      'Settings',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ),
            Expanded
            (
              flex: 4,
              child: MediaQuery.removePadding
              (
                context: context,
                removeTop: true,
                child: ListView.separated
                (
                  itemCount: settings.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(height: 1.0), 
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
                  {
                    return settings[index];
                  }       
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As said by the error message, the theme could change. So your list is not static

Comment: A typical example of when the theme could change is dark mode

Answer (score 0):

`context` is available after the first build. Because of that you can't use it like that in `initState()`. You can use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {});` inside `initState()` there you will have the `context` available

Try this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // Use context here
      settings =     
      [
        Text(
          'Account',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
        ),
      //...... Do all initializations that require context here
      ]
    });
}
```

Also, you can't `setState()` in `initState()`. `setState()` is for generating a rebuild. In `initState()` is run before the first build, so there's nothing to rebuild. Everything you set in `initState()` will be available in your first build

Comment: Misleading. Context is available, it is Theme that is not available. You can use context freely otherwise

Comment: Hi Remi! Thank you for your comment. Can you help me update my answer so It's not misleading? Thanks